# jquery stop tabs from changing url

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use twitter bootstrap to show tabs. when a tab is called url should change from:

```
example.com/controller
```

to

```
example.com/controller#tabid
```

but in my code it does not happen unless I remove jquery. why does jquery stop url from being changed?

this is my code:
http://jsbin.com/oraFITI/1/edit

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#store">store</a>
    </li>
        <li class="">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#favorite">Favorite</a>
    </li>   
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="content">
  <div id="about" class="tab-pane active">about content</div>
  <div id="profile" class="tab-pane">profile content</div>
  <div id="store" class="tab-pane">store content</div>
  <div id="favorite" class="tab-pane">favorite content</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bootstrap.js require jquery. I think the behaviour you see is the expected behaviour

Comment: maybe you are right. URL does not change when clicking on tabs. that's what i don't expect.

Comment: you are more looking for a nav bar then as i understand it

Comment: i just want to imitate this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: In this example, where do you see URL being updated with hash? I'm sure anchor tags have just their default behaviour prevented, you could just override handler

Comment: i see url with hash on tabs but when i click on them the url with hash does not appear

Comment: Really i'm confused, you want hash in URL or not? Like i said, it is expected behaviour to not see hash

Comment: but i want to see hash in url on top of browser after click

Comment: `$('.nav-tabs a').on('click',function(){
   window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
});` you could still update hash but this will not update browser history as it should. You should set logic using onhashchange handler e.g if user directly access page with hash, the corresponding tab should be shown. But again, this is not usually the purpose of a tab component

Comment: thanks, you may send it as answer so i can approve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still set your own click handler:

```
$('.nav-tabs a').on('click',function(){ window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); });
```